# Keypress about not allowing testers inputing 2 digits in a textbox in vba

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, keypress

I have a code that will not allow to press 0,1 and 8 up

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
 Select Case KeyAscii
     Case Asc("2") To Asc("8")
     Case Else
         KeyAscii = 0
         MsgBox "Input should be 2 to 8 only!"
 End Select
 End Sub
```

but my problem is if I inputed 22, 33, 44, 555,666 and 888 to it, the msgbox won' t run.

My Goal is to guard the textbox to only 2 to 8.

Comment: couldn't you just disable textbox1 after one successful input digit?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. First you say pressing 0, 1, and 8 aren't allowed. Then you say you're trying to ensure the textbox only contains 2's and 8's, which contradicts the first statement. Your code needs to look at `Len(TextBox1.Text)` and set `KeyAscii.Value` to `0` when that length is `1`, effectively blocking everything but the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish what you need:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If Val(TextBox1.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)) < 2 Or Val(TextBox1.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)) > 8 Then
      KeyAscii = 0
      MsgBox "Input should be 2 to 8 only!"
   End If
End Sub
```

The basic idea is to evaluate what the value of the text box is going to be and respond appropriately.